# Find the area bounded by the curve $x^4+y^4=x^2+y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, area

I am stuck with this problem which deals with evaluating an Area
The problem reads :

> Find the area bounded by the curve $x^4+y^4=x^2+y^2$.

I tried factorizing the expression and expressing $y$ in terms of $x$, not able to proceed with that idea. Someone please help me out.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1876593.

Answer (score 4):

Expressing the curve in polar coordinates, we have\begin{align}x^4+y^4=x^2+y^2&\iff\rho^4\cos^4\theta+\rho^4\sin^4\theta=\rho^2\\&\iff\rho=\frac1{\sqrt{\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta}}.\end{align}Hence, the area that you're after is\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1/\sqrt{\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta}}\rho\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac2{3+\cos(4\theta)}\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\pi\sqrt2.\end{align}

Comment: To get an intuitive reason on why you should express it in polar coordinates, graph it. You should note that it has some radial symmetry (i.e. you can rotate it and get the same figure). The area also doesn't intersect itself when sweeping radially. There is also an $x^2+y^2$ in the equation. Generally, when at least two of these conditions hold, I will try and look at it radially.

Comment: A little detail: I would write the area with a simple integral at once: $\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac12 \rho^2 d\theta $ (because this formula is in tables).

Comment: Thank you for your solution @José Carlos Santos

Comment: I suggest that you mark one of the answers as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Use polar co-ordinates $x=r \cos t, y=r \sin t$, then this curve is $$r^2=\frac{1}{\sin^4 t+ \cos^4 t}=\ $$, the area the area is
$$A=4 ~ \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} r^2 dt=2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\cos^4 t+\sin^4 t}dt =2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec^4 t}{1+\tan^4 t} dt $$
Let $z=\tan t \implies dz=\sec^2 t dt$
$$=2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1+z^2}{1+z^4} dz=2 \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1+1/z^2}{z^2+1/z^2}=2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1+1/z^2}{(z-1/z)^2+2}$$ $$\implies A=2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{du}{u^2+2}=\sqrt{2} \pi.$$

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Z Ahmed

Comment: The way you transform $2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\cos^4 t+\sin^4 t}dt$ into $2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1+z^2}{1+z^4} dz$ isn't evident...

Comment: @Jean Marie You may see now I have added some more stuff. Here I take $z=\tan t$

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this without using polar coordinates- but not easy.  I would start by noting that only even powers of x and y are involved so the graph of this is symmetric about the x and y axes.  That means that we can calculate the area for x and y positive and multiply by 4.

There is a little problem in that y is not a function of x even in the first quadrant.  Differentiating with respect to y gives $4x^3x'+ 4y^3= 2xx'+ 2y$, $(4x^3- 2x)x'= 2y- 4y^3$.  Setting x'= 0, for a maximum or minimum, $2y- 4y^3= 2y(1- 2y^2)= 0$. That has three roots, y= 0, $y= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, and $y= -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. y= 0 gives $x^4= x^2$ in the original equation which gives $x^2= 1$, $x= \pm 1$.
$y= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ gives $x^4- x^2= \frac{1}{4}- \frac{1}{2}= -\frac{1}{4}$.  Letting $z= x^2$, $z^2- z+ \frac{1}{4}= (z- \frac{1}{2})^2= 0$ so $z^2= x^2= \frac{1}{2}$.  Since we are in the first quadrant, $x= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

For x between 0 and $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ we can solve y^4- y^2+ (x^4- x^2)= 0 using the quadratic formula: $y= \frac{1+ \sqrt{1- 4(x^4- x^2)}}{2}$.
$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} 1+ \sqrt{1- 4(x^4-x^2)}dx$.  But then we have to integrate from x= $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ to 1:  $\int_\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}^1 \sqrt{1- 4(x^4- x^2)}dx$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $y^2$ instead of $y$ in 4th last line ?

Comment: Also I am not able understand the functions you are integrating . Please elaborate on your answer , I am a high school student and I don't know polar coordinate integration much . I am keenly waiting for edits in solution .